# Vugen - How to submit data along with a redirected url

Tags: loadrunner, vugen

I have some data that I am submitting in a web_submit_data request. This request gets a response code of Http code 302. Load runner implicitly handles the redirection and user is navigated to redirected url. However the data that I wanted to submit in the initial request is lost. No data is getting submitted in the redirected url. Can someone please guide on how to address this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your redirect URL is being defined by your server, not by your client.  A better question to ask is why the server is responding with an incorrect redirect?

Comment: Thank you for the response James. The original Post with path /register is redirected to /register?filter=All which again is redirected to /register?filter=All which is then processed for submission. The data sent with original request is lost in between the two redirects and is resulting in no data being submitted. If it is worth mentioning, the test result on replaying the script still shows Pass even though the data is not getting submitted and the result summary displays a content, "Resource of content type "DummyContentType" loaded successfully".

Comment: "Pass" in this context simply means a valid HTTP 2xx page was loaded at the end.   Look to your server admin.  If they are scrubbing data it is on their end.   Also, two redirects?  This would be abyssmal from a scalability perspective.  Limit it to one redirect (max), ideally a 301 which could be cached by your CDN provider

Answer (score 0):

Thank you James. Since the application I worked on was developed in Ruby on Rails. The redirection was not really causing the issue here. Once I correlated the values correctly, everything fell in place.